# react-webcam : Video missing metadatas

Tags: reactjs

Here is my current code :

```
const webcamRef = useRef(null);
var mediaRecorderRef = useRef(null);
const [capturing, setCapturing] = useState(false);
const [capturedOnce, setCaptured] = useState(false);
const [recordedChunks, setRecordedChunks] = useState([]);
```

```
const handleStartCaptureClick = useCallback(() => {
    setRecordedChunks([]);
    setCapturing(true);
    
    mediaRecorderRef.current = new MediaRecorder(webcamRef.current.stream, {
        mimeType: "video/webm"
    });

    mediaRecorderRef.current.addEventListener(
        "dataavailable",
        handleDataAvailable
    );
    mediaRecorderRef.current.start();

    if(props.time != undefined && props.time != null && props.time != [] && props.time[props.question] != null) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            handleStopCaptureClick();
        }, props.time[props.question-1] * 1000);
    }
    
}, [mediaRecorderRef, webcamRef, setCapturing]);
```

```
const sendCapture = () => {
    if (recordedChunks.length) {
        const blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, {
            type: "video/webm"
        });
        
        const filename = "Question"+ props.question + '.webm';

        const file = new File(recordedChunks, filename, { type: 'video/webm' });

        const data = new FormData();
        data.append('file', file);

        axios.post("http://localhost:3001/upload", data)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.statusText);
        })
        setRecordedChunks([]);
    }
}
```

As you can see from my code, i'm currently saving them as webm because it's the file format that has the less missing metadatas but it's still missing some, like its fps duration and bitrates.
When i use mp4 instead of webm it's even worse, it's also missing its resolution (width and height)

Is there a way to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-encoding the videos fixes those missing metadatas.